# What are the differences between Bayesian filters and adaptive filters?

Tags: stochastic-processes, hidden-markov-model, kalman-filter, state-space-models, particle-filter

I am learning about state estimation and I am having difficulty understanding the difference between Bayesian filters such as Kalman filter and particle filters compared to adaptive filters. According to [this tutorial](https://people.kth.se/~bo/Vikram/filter.pdf), [adaptive filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_filter#LMS_algorithm) are stochastic approximators such as [LMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_filter#LMS_algorithm) and [RLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter) and they assume that state varies very slowly with unknown dynamics. Could you please explain the main differences between these state estimation categories?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "adaptive filters" are, but from a statistical standpoint

1. recursive least squares is a special case of the Kalman filter for models with state dynamics that are noiseless, and
2. particle filters are simulation-based approximations to the filtering recursions. Instead of keeping track of several numbers that change from time point to time point (the Kalman filter keeps track of a mean vector and a covariance matrix), they keep track of a large collection of weighted samples. They are much slower, more difficult to program, and harder to justify mathematically than closed-form filters, so they should really only be used for models where, say, the Kalman filter isn't suitable. This might happen, for instance, when either the state transition and/or the observation equation aren't normal, or one of them isn't "linear".